# Secret Christmas bash hats

Tags: discussion, winterbash-2013

I just got a secret *Johnny Three-hats* hat on ELU. I assume, by its name, that I got it for having gotten three hats in one day (?), but there was no description for this one like there is for the other, non-secret ones.

So … how do we know what we get secret hats for, if their description just says, “This is a secret hat”?

Comment: You need to be on *double secret probation* to get an answer to that question.

Answer (score 2):

The current stance is ["The secret hats are secret for a reason"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211709/135907). Each year more secret than the last. Perhaps next year you'll be awarded secret hats without even noticing.

That being said, your description is entirely correct. Three hats in the same day. Do note that some hats such as Frosty are technically awarded the *next* day. So if you have two hats today, and are waiting for Frosty to get you the Three-Hat hat, don't hold your breath. It will count as two hats for today, one hat for tomorrow. Keep that in mind when collecting. Make sure to *see* three new hats all on the same day.

Comment: Truth be told, I haven’t been collecting hats, really. The only hat I’ve specifically gone for is the Marauder one (mostly because I love getting lost in old Irish dictionaries); the rest have just sort of randomly happened at some point. I still have no idea how many hats there even are, or what you get them for. :-)

Comment: Well, most hats are described [right on the Winter Bash page](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/). You get there by clicking the "Winter Bash" link in the top left corner of the eponymous dropdown. As to secret hats, there are of course [some spoilers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212799/how-do-i-get-the-winterbash-2013-secret-hats) making the rounds. If you need more help still, just drop by in our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage) and ask around. And if you prefer for it to be a complete surprise, more power to you!

Comment: Oh, and some hats are *only* available in chat. You can't get them anywhere else. There's even a limited-edition 2014 hat that can only be awarded *right now*, in the next 24 hours, and only in chat. So [do drop by to say hello](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage). Nobody bites.

Comment: And remember that we are competing against other sites to see who can get the most hats! And you don't have to wear hats to earn them.